# Using Tweepy, is there a way to be able to interact with the UTC time that 'created_at' returns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy, twitterapi-python

In my case, I want to be able to get what's returned by 'created_at' and  use it in an if statement or loop or anything else.

```
mentions = api.mentions_timeline(tweet_mode="extended")

for tweet in reversed(mentions):
    created_at_id = tweet.id 
    created_at = tweet.created_at 
    print(f"tweet was made at {created_at}")

tweet was made at 2021-05-14 00:22:23 # This is what is printed
```

This is fine and dandy, the time is returned in UTC format but what if I wanted to compare the time and date (just time if possible) and use it in a statement?

```
if *hour of the tweet* 12 hours before datetime.datetime.now():
    print("yes")
# Some pseudocode here because I still have to figure out how to be able to compare the current date
```

So the question stands, how could I access the *time* of the tweet so I can use it in a statement? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the date format for *hour of the tweet*.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I edited the post! Here is what is printed though `tweet was made at 2021-05-14 00:22:23`

Comment: So you only want tweets that were posted 12 hours between this sample date?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to go for although I'm not entirely sure how to approach @Lifeiscomplex Edit: Also not just this date, I have a for loop that returns tweets in mentions_timeline but I would like that for loop to only return tweets within a certain time or date

Comment: is **created_at = tweet.created_at**  a *string* or a *datetime* object.

Comment: `print(type(created_at))` returns `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.  If not, I will correct it.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

twelve_hours_before = (datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=12)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
time_string = '2021-05-14 23:35:23'

# use your datetime object for parse(time_string).
if parse(twelve_hours_before) <= parse(time_string): 
    print('yes')
```

Comment: Okay! Very interesting, I am going to implement this into the bot and see what happens! I'll be right back

Comment: LMK if it worked for you.  If it did please accept my answer.

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you and I accepted it @Life is complex

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you solve your issue.  Happy Coding!!